# JQUERY AJAX call returning PHP page contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I'm requesting a file named `uuid.php`, and when I request it via JQUERY AJAX, it returns the contents of that `php` file. I've been on multiple other Stack Overflow posts describing the error, and I couldn't get a good answer for my problem.

**JQUERY request:**

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "uuid.php",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {"kahoot":"2020"},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

**uuid.php**

```
<?php
$query=$_POST['kahoot']
$url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/?query='.$query;
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo json_encode(array(data=>$contents));
?>
```

I've tried the `PHP` code outside of this project, and it works fine. There were no errors, but when I put it into the project it doesn't work. Is this an error with AJAX?

Comment: Hello, Can you share the error you have? you can i try to find it via console(F12)

Comment: Sure! ```<?php
$query=$_POST['kahoot']
$url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/?query='.$query;
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo json_encode(array(data=>$contents));
?>```

Comment: Yes, I know. I want to read, an return it.

Comment: Can you share more details? Does the call return the source code of that PHP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that visiting the URL directly (https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/?query=kahoot) returns a JSON response so the json_encode may be more that needed.

Does the output from this look any better:

```
<?php
$query=$_POST['kahoot']
$url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/?query='.$query;
echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: Sadly, no. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: It's the exact same as the `uuid.php` contents: ```<?php
$query=$_POST['kahoot']
$url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/?query='.$query;
echo file_get_contents($url);
?>```

Comment: In that case the PHP file is not being parsed by your php implementation, presumably you are working on a local development setup where php is working under normal circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add ; in this line:

```
$query=$_POST['kahoot']
```

Comment: Sorry about that! It didn't change the output though...

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I tested your codes and they are working. Could you please check your uuid.php file type? Probably it's not defined as php file, that's the problem.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: what else am I supposed to say? I just mentioned he forget to add a semicolon

Comment: "I've tried the PHP code outside of this project, and it works fine" - that lets me think that the missing semicolon is not related to the given problem. Also, the OP stated that he changed this error and the original problem did not vanish

Answer (score 0):

Your JS file is ok,
I have changed your PHP code a bit:

```
<?php
    $query=$_POST['kahoot'];
    $url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/?query='.$query;
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    echo json_encode(array($contents));
?>
```

First of all you have forget to add `;` on the first row.

And I've updated the last row to this:

`echo json_encode(array($contents));` instand of
`echo json_encode(array(data=>$contents));`

That should do.